# Changing views iphone

Tags: iphone

this is a very noobie question although I have had quite a bit of experience iphone development.

I have a client who wants an app with various screnns, but does not want to use built in iphone navigation, but instead wants to have buttons on the screens.  All I can find is a load of 14 year olds giving tutorials on MVC or using different views in the same nib.

Does anybody know what apples suggested way of doing this is as I can imagine it been a mind field.

Many thanks

Comment: How will you want to do your navigation? Do you want to tap a button and slide a view in? You want to flip it around? You say you do not wan't the 'standard' navigation, but what do you want?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should have followed the MVC tutorials of the 14 year old guys.

Then you would know that you could use the built in iphone navigation controllers (ie UITabBarController, UINavigationController) without their standard view counterparts (ie UITabBar, UINavigationBar).

Answer (score 0):

You could always just draw buttons on the screen in interface builder and use custom images for the normal/highlighted states.

When the button is pressed it's up to you what you'd like to do with the received buttonclick method being invoked... the usual way is with the standard navigation system which can optionally have a navigation bar at the top with (back) button, title, etc...  and you push/pop viewcontrollers in a hierarchical way.  You can just turn the title (or change for your own style) but it does enforce a hierarchical structure.

If you don't want hierarchical navigation of your screens you can either do this with your own custom navigation controller than handles which viewcontroller is currently visible or you could use a thirdparty component like three60 which allows you to navigate around like a webbrowser does on webpages.

You may also want to take a look at Corona which is more for games but would allow you to do a totally custom interface with all sorts of custom transitions and just needs you to write lua... that said it will limit you on using their engine with this approach as you can't get to the ObjC level.

Finally one last approach is simply to use webview and pick up the clicked links so you design your app via webpages... rather ugly approach but can work well if you're very familiar with HTML.